# some struct redefinition errors

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

```
struct NAMESTRUCT
{
    int ID;
    std::string DESC;
};
 struct NAMESTRUCT NAME;
 NAME.ID = 1;
 NAME.DESC = "STUFF";
```

ERRORS:

```
IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
IntelliSense: expected a ';'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2371: 'NAME' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

I don't know what i did wrong... please help.

EDIT:
THIS IS MY REAL CODE:

```
//some includes

struct ERRORTYPES
{
    int ID;
    std::string DESC;
};
 ERRORTYPES UNERROR;
 UNERROR.ID = 1;
 UNERROR.DESC = "UNKNWON ERROR";
//more code
```

.... and yes this is not in a function, should i put it in a function?

Comment: Is that your real code? You cannot have expressions such as `NAME>ID = 1;` outside of functions.

Comment: Yes… the confusing bit is that you haven't told us what those messages are pointing at. The `struct` declaration could actually be inside a function, and then this would be valid, if somewhat unusual, code.

Comment: Don't use the keyword `struct` when declaring variables.

Comment: You are assigning a character array (many characters), "STUFF", to a character variable (only holds 1 character).

Comment: You are using C-Style strings.  Use `std::string`.

Comment: I just put half the code in a class and the other in the INIT function i got and now it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as you made changes to your question invalidating the accepted answer. I would've otherwise reverted the changes but there appears to be some confusion as to what your actual (original) code looks like. Please post complete code that, when compiled, would give the exact same problems as stated in the question in future questions and edit this question in the same way if you think it might be useful to future visitors. And yes, I'm pretty sure things like `UNERROR.ID = 1;` needs to be in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some issues that I found:

**Don't use `struct` for variables**
When declaring variables, use the name of the structure:

```
NAMESTRUCT NAME;
```

**Character variables hold 1 character only.**
You are assigning a string, "STUFF" (many characters), to a character variable (that holds only one character).  This is known as buffer overflow.  Bad.

**Use `std::string` for text strings.**
Make your life a lot easier by using `std::string` for strings.  Otherwise you have to deal with pointers, memory allocation and deallocation.  From the number of questions on StackOverlow about this topic, you really don't want to go that route, std::string is much easier.

**String literals are pointers to characters.**
String literals such as "STUFF" are sequences of many characters with a terminating '\0' character, known as a C-Style string.  On the Right Hand Side (RHS) of an assignment, they are represented by a pointer to the sequence of characters.  If you want to use C-Style strings, you will need either a `char *` (pointer to character) variable or `char[]` (array of characters) variable.

If you use the pointer variable, remember that assignment only copies the location or address of the C-Style string, not the contents.  You'll have to use `strncpy` to copy the contents.  Also remember that a pointer only points to things.  You still need to allocate memory to hold the contents.

If you use the array of characters variable, remember to allocate and extra slot for the terminating '\0' (nul) character.  Also remember to always check the length of the source string before copying into the array.

**Assignments in functions**
You can assign values to variables in two places:  functions or global area.  In the global area, assignment occurs when you define a variable; otherwise it must occur in a function.

**Coding Style**
A common coding style is to use all UPPERCASE for constants.  You should determine the style for type names and variable names, and prefer to keep them different.  For example, type names would begin with a capital letter followed by lowercase: `struct Namestruct` and variable names all lower case: `Namestruct name;`.